# Deployment Target Options Missing in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to run an android app on a physical device.

In the IntelliJ instructions [here](https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-an-android-run-debug-configuration.html) it says I can do so by changing settings in the "Deployment Target Options" area.

I do not see this area in IntelliJ however.

Here is an image:

[image]

Let me know if there is any further information I can provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation needs to be corrected. Please use this drop-down next to run configuration selector to select the device:

[image]

Comment: In the latest intellij this 'available' devices dropdown list is not available.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are favoring the new idea ui then there is no direct option to select target device however option still exist but hidden.

Simply double tap "shift" then type "Select Device"

[image]